# MySQL Merging two tables with precedence

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

In a MySQL database, I have 2 tables with the following sample data. The table key is variable_id.

**table_1**

```
   **variable_id** **release_id**  
     3               10
     5               10
```

**table_2**

```
   **variable_id** **release_id**  
     1               01
     2               15
     3               15
     4               20
     5               25
```

I want to be able to merge the two tables, with the rows in table_1 having precedence over the rows in table_2.

The result set should be:

```
   **variable_id** **release_id**  
     1               01
     2               15
     3               10
     4               20
     5               10
```

Please help me with the MySQL SQL to accomplish this. I tried doing a union of left and right joins but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You could take the rows from `table_1` and then `union all` them the extra rows from `table_2`. Clunky, but should get the job done:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   table_2
WHERE  variable_id NOT IN (SELECT variable_id FROM table_1)
```

Comment: so long as variable_id in table_1 is never null

Comment: @Drew OP stated that "The table key is variable_id". I assume that means a primary key, which by definition, cannot be `null`.

Comment: just for the next guy that comes along :>

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT table_2.variable_id, 
       IFNULL(table_1.release_id, table_2.release_id) release_id
FROM table_2 
LEFT JOIN table_1 
ON table_2.variable_id = table_1.variable_id
```